# Trying to make the header height auto

Tags: css

[My website here](http://www.averylawoffice.ca/averywordpress) is a wordpress website but I believe the only thing I need to fix for an issue I'm having is the header height. The home page as a rotating banner which is 403px high and then all other pages have a header image of 303px high. I'm just trying to get the header height to be auto so the #container will automatically hug the bottom of the banner no matter it's height.

CSS

```
header { width: 960px; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; display: block;}

#container { width: 960px; margin: 20px auto; padding: 0 1.5em;}
```

What else should there be so the #container realizes that the header is there?

### UPDATE:

NEW HTML

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div><!-- end of container-->
```

NEW CSS

```
#banner { 
    width: 960px;      /* same with already defined */
    height: 403px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

The only thinkg i did slightly differently was place the navigation under the header instead of the banner as it was underneath the banner of which i don't want. It looks the same however the  doesn't seem to be doing anything differently then what I had previously. I still have that gap on the blog page under the banner.

I appreciate the help Zuul. I do think I have a bit more to go and then we can figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: unless the content is floated or absolutely positioned, the container should expand automatically - if the problem is that the content is being floated, then I'd suggest applying overflow: hidden; to the container

Comment: @kinakuta, You didn't saw the link did you? ;) There are `position:absolute` and `float` elements all around :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, my eyes just glossed right over the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the layout doesn't lay over the `header` tag, there are some elements positioned weirdly that are causing several problems:

**This is a list of things to do in order to rectify the layout flow:**

#### 1)

Remove the `<div id="banner">` from within the `<nav id="main-navigation">`.

The `<nav id="main-navigation">` is set to `height:70px` and the slider is far taller than that.

**Place it** as a child of the `<header>` **or** after the `<header>` and before the `<div id="container">`.

**e.g,**

```
<header>...</header>
<div id="banner">...</div>     <!-- here is better -->
<div id="container">...</div>
```

---

#### 2)

After the first step, you can then remove from your `#banner` the following CSS:

**REMOVE**

```
#banner {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 69px;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**ADD**

```
#banner {
    width: 960px;      /* same with already defined */
    height: 403px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

#### 3)

The step 01 and 02 should fix the `#banner` position along with the `header` height issue.

Now remains fixing the `#container` that contains floated elements and should be cleared at the end.

Here, your current class `clearfix` will not work, contains to many declarations, I would suggest:

```
<div id="container">

   <div id="main">...</div>
   <aside>...</aside>

   <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

Adding that new `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` at the very end of the `#container` will allow the `float` to be cleared and the document flow to resume normally.

---

## EDITED

First phase is done, now the only thing you need to do is to remove the `height` from the `#banner`, and the gap will go away.

```
#banner {
    width: 960px;      /* keep this */
    margin: 0 auto;    /* keep this */
}
```

Comment: @Amber, feel free to apply this and return to request any further assistance to properly fix the issue if some of the suggestions don't reach 100% of the intended goal.

Comment: thanks for the help! It's coming along however it's not much different regarding the gap under the banner on the blog page. Please see updated question with stats.

Comment: @Amber, see my **edited** at the end of my answer with the solution for that.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help. It's much appreciated. So what was I doing wrong? Should I of not put both the navigation and banner in the header?

Comment: You can have them both in the `header`, you just couldn't have the `#banner` inside the `#main-navigation` due to the `height` difference between them... If you see my **e.g.,** at **1)**, you'll see that the one being moved from your original HTML was the `#banner`, and only outside the `header` due to cross-page issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

add a `div` with a `style` of `clear:both` just before your container div ends. This will allow to make the container div's height according to the contents inside it. You can make a class named `clear` and inside it you can put this style so that you can use this `class` anywhere in your website.

Comment: your container div will have the height of 0px if you remove the padding from it.

Comment: I kind of get what you mean. You want me to put a div inside the container div and have the style clear:both? Why not above it?

Comment: because after seeing your site I've found that your its you container div that didn't get the whole height of the content inside it. This is because there are some or at least one element floated and for this floated element your container isn't getting any height. For best practice I suggested to give the clear div below every content. And if you place this clear div above the container div, it'll clear any float element above it not the floats inside the container.